# ImportError with whitenoise.django

Tags: django, whitenoise

I've installed whitenoise with command:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

But when I'm moving on whitenoise.django there is only this error:

```
raise ImportError(
        '\n\n'
        'Your WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0\n'
        'This can be fixed by following the upgrade instructions at:\n'
        'http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0\n'
        '\
```

Comment: The error is quite clear: you need to fix your configuration to make it compatible with WhiteNoise v4.0. Have you tried following the upgrade instructions as mentioned in the error?

Answer (score 0):

There are step-by-step instructions on using WhiteNoise with Django here:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html